# Tag Cleanup: rename [solar] to [solar-cell]

Tags: support, tags

**Resolved**

All [solar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar) should be [solar-cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-cell), which is less vague.

Maybe make [photovoltaic-cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaic-cell) or [pv-cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pv-cell) point to it too, though that will probably never be a problem.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/solar/synonyms

Comment: @endolith: That's backwards from what I'm proposing.  [solar] is vague.

Comment: For what else would `[solar]` be used?

Comment: @NickT, you can submit this synonym yourself. and other can vote on it.

Comment: @Kortuk, I can't because [solar] occurs more often than [solar-cell].  I could just manually fix them all, but then they all get bumped.

Comment: @nickT, I see your issue, When I look at the tags [Solar-Power] seems to be a better name, what do you think?

Comment: Hey @NickT, accept an answer so the [Community](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user doesn't bump this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all taken care of.

Solar now redirects to solar-cell. If this does not work out well we can fix it in the future.